# VM works in NAT mode but not bridged mode?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

Virtual box running on Windows 10 x64 pro.

I have an ubuntu server VM running in bridged mode and it has an active internet connection.

However, when I try to run other VMs, while still running the Ubuntu VM, the other VMs don't have internet access unless I put them in NAT mode not bridged mode.

Why? I don't like how nat mode puts the VM in a different subnet.

Gateway for my router is 10.12.1.1. Looking on my NAT VM, the gateway is 10.0.2.2.

Comment: Do you have some sort of limitation on the number of devices connected to your router? Like some statement in your Internet subscription ToS.

Comment: Nope. But does it matter that I only have one ethernet port on my desktop? Or can it handle running multiple virtual internet connections through one ethernet port?

Comment: The number of network interfaces isn’t related to bridging at all.